# Is "as" correct here?

Tags: grammar

Outside his house, several cars are parked **as** a group of people **have** gathered to demonstrate.

- Is **as** natural here? Would **and** be better?
- Would it also be correct if I had written "a group of people **has** gathered"?

Comment: Would prefer **as a group of people gather to demonstrate**. Sounds better to me. Group (collective noun) can take singular or plural. Google **collective nouns singular plural** for extensive guidance.

Comment: I would interpret _as_ here as meaning _because_, implying that the parked cars belong to the demonstrators.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, agreed; it makes more sense that way.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree with you.My answer is also “because”

Answer (score 1):

I think the first problem is that it is not natural. Backing up let's say the situation was,

John drove home from work, exhausted. As he turned onto his street he sighed in frustration. He would have to park a block away again! Outside his house, several cars *were* parked. A group of people were gathered to demonstrate, again.

or

cars *were* parked and group of people were gathered to demonstrate, again.

Without knowing the context the verb 'are' seems awkward. And without knowing what was important in the story, we can't really tell whether a full stop or 'and' was better... but 'as' is just awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Because would be better than as. If you want to use as to mean because, you need to put a comma before it, otherwise it reads as if the cars are parked in a group.

The sentence doesn't sound natural though, due to the verb tense. If you are recounting a story it would be normal to use the past tense. I would also change the ordering in the sentence:

Several cars were parked outside his house, as a group of people had gathered to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

They are saying as because its means the cars belong to the people who are gathering.

if i say:

> Outside his house, several cars are parked and a group of people have gathered to demonstrate.

^this actually means there are several cars parked in a group and a group of people gathered to demonstarte^

meaning:

> The several cars have nothing to do with the people and don't belong to them

But the several cars do have something to do with the people.Beacuse it is their cars.Beacuse it says:

> Several cars have gathered AS a group of people gathered to demonstrate: (meaning they came with the/their car)

Also

> Have is used with the pronouns I, you, we, and they, while has is used with he, she, and it.